# Layout does not work in portrait mode

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:padding="1dip" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:text="Total Pregnancies"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:text="10"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="160dp"
            android:text="Full Term"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="75dp"
            android:text="11"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="190dp"
            android:text="Premature"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:text="12"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:padding="1dip" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:text="Multiples"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="85dp"
            android:text="16"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="160dp"
            android:text="Living"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="95dp"
            android:text="17"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="1dip" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:text="Ab Included"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="70dp"
            android:text="13"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="160dp"
            android:text="Ab Spontaneous"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:text="14"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="190dp"
            android:text="Ectopics"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="35dp"
            android:text="15"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Can anyone tell me whats wrong with this layout as it seems not working in `portrait` mode, but perfectly fits the screen when it comes to `landscape`. I have attached the screen shot of what i am trying to do, the above is a `lists` which is added to a `ListView`.

**Update:**

The View gets gets cluttered when in portrait mode.

Comment: @NiravRanpara: why do u need the manifest file.... it gets cluttered when in portrait mode.

Comment: why do you need ans ?

Comment: @Kevin, It's hard to understand the issue, "gets cluttered" doesn't tell much.

Comment: @Kevin Well, it's quite obvious that the content will take a lot of space (width), especially due to the paddings you've set. @NiravRanpara How would the `manifest` make any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems with what you've written:

1. You assume that the width would suffice no matter what is the screen . You might want to add a [horizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html) or use a different layout.
2. You have the same id for each of the layouts.
3. Why do you have android:orientation="vertical" for your RelativeLayout?

Comment: I did the two and three, but it did not work.... the right side part is invisible... it just shows the first two columns...

Comment: @Kevin #1 is the real answer here.

Comment: @Kevin In order to be sure there is enough space, set a different background color for each of the items, or set a smaller width for them, or run the app on a device/emulator which has a lot of width space.

Comment: @androiddeveloper: horizontal is working, but i don't want the scroll to see the last items... should i reduce the width... i don't want to load a different layout for potrait mode.

Comment: @Kevin You have to understand some things about developing for Android: there are plenty of different screens . Some are smaller than your device, some are larger. Text should not be too small or else it would be hard to read. There are many other solutions other than using so many linearLayouts (for example using TableLayout or GridLayout). You are the one that should decide what is best for your app.

Comment: @Kevin If you wish, you can have different layouts for different screens, depending on the space you have. In any case, I suggest reading more about this issue (which is one of the advantages and disadvantages of developing for Android) , for example here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 1):

All the `LinearLayout`s have the same id `linearLayout1`. I think you should give different ids to different views.